# Pass a data structure in to a macro for filling in

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to solve a problem: I need to create a map from passed-in values, but while the symbol names for the values are consistent, the *keys* they map to are not. For instance: I might be passed a value that is a user ID. In the code, I can always use the symbol `user-id` -- but depending on other factors, I might need to make a map `{"userId" user-id}` or `{"user_id" user-id}` or `{:user-id user-id}` or -- well, you get the picture.

I can write a macro that gets me part-way there:

```
(defmacro user1 [user-id] `{"userId" ~user-id}
(defmacro user2 [user-id] `{"user_id" ~user-id}
```

But what I'd much rather do is define a set of maps, then combine them with a given set of symbols:

```
(def user-id-map-1 `{"userId" `user-id}
(defn combiner [m user-id] m)            ;; <-- Around here, a miracle occurs.
```

I can't figure out how to get this evaluation to occur. It seems like I *should* be able to make a map containing un-evaluated symbols, then look up those symbols in the lexical scope of a function or macro that binds those symbols as locals -- but *how*?

Comment: There are two great answers to this now; I wish I could mark both as correct. Thank you, clever people of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of standardizing your symbolic names, use maps with *standard keyword keys*. You don't need to go near macros, and you can turn your maps into records if need be without much trouble.

What you know as

```
(def user1 {:id 3124, :surname "Adabolo", :forenames ["Julia" "Frances"]})
```

... can be transformed by mapping the keys with whatever function you choose:

```
(defn map-keys [keymap m]
  (zipmap (map keymap (keys m)) (vals m)))
```

For example,

```
(map-keys name user1)
;{"id" 3124, "surname" "Adabolo", "forenames" ["Julia" "Frances"]}
```

or

```
(map-keys {:id :user-id, :surname :family-name} user1)
;{:user-id 3124, :family-name "Adabolo", nil ["Julia" "Frances"]}
```

If you want rid of the `nil` entry, wrap the expression in `(dissoc ... nil)`:

```
(defn map-keys [keymap m]
  (dissoc
    (zipmap (map keymap (keys m)) (vals m))
    nil))
```

Then

```
(map-keys {:id :user-id, :surname :family-name} user1)
;{:user-id 3124, :family-name "Adabolo"}
```

---

I see from [Michał Marczyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580215/1562315), which has priority, that the above essentially rewrites `clojure.set/rename-keys`, which, however ...

- leaves missing keys untouched:

For example,

```
(clojure.set/rename-keys user1 {:id :user-id, :surname :family-name})
;{:user-id 3124, :forenames ["Julia" "Frances"], :family-name "Adabolo"}
```

- doesn't work with normal functions:

For example,

```
(clojure.set/rename-keys user1 name)
;IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$name ...
```

If you forego the use of `false` and `nil` as keys, you can leave missing keys untouched and still use normal functions:

```
(defn map-keys [keymap m]
  (zipmap (map #(or (keymap %) %) (keys m)) (vals m)))
```

Then

```
(map-keys {:id :user-id, :surname :family-name} user1)
;{:user-id 3124, :family-name "Adabolo", :forenames ["Julia" "Frances"]}
```

Comment: Ah, very clever! And you saved me a bunch of time on dealing with missing keys -- very good.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting your passed-in values in a map keyed by keywords forged from the formal parameter names:

```
(defmacro zipfn [map-name arglist & body]
  `(fn ~arglist
     (let [~map-name (zipmap ~(mapv keyword arglist) ~arglist)]
       ~@body)))
```

Example of use:

```
((zipfn argmap [x y z]
   argmap)
 1 2 3)
;= {:z 3, :y 2, :x 1}
```

Better yet, don't use macros:

```
;; could take varargs for ks (though it would then need another name)
(defn curried-zipmap [ks]
  #(zipmap ks %))

((curried-zipmap [:x :y :z]) [1 2 3])
;= {:z 3, :y 2, :x 1}
```

Then you could rekey this map using `clojure.set/rename-keys`:

```
(clojure.set/rename-keys {:z 3, :y 2, :x 1} {:z "z" :y "y" :x "x"})
;= {"x" 1, "z" 3, "y" 2}
```

The second map here is the "translation map" for the keys; you can construct in by merging maps like `{:x "x"}` describing how the individual keys ought to be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you described I can't find a reason to use macros.

I'd recommend something like

```
(defn assoc-user-id 
  [m user-id other-factors]
  (assoc m (key-for other-factors) user-id))
```

Where you implement `key-for` so that it selects the key based on `other-factors`.